Azure Access Review Begin date setup and time
I have set it up the access review and scheduled for today's date. When the access begin date will start? there is no Time to configure and its just a date,  automatic email will trigger on the same time when i scheduled the setup on the begin date?

Could you include more details like how you set up the access review by adding Portal images and steps?
